# sqoop password containing semicolon

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

All,

I am facing issue in executing sqoop command if semicolon is part of password. How to make sqoop accept literal string as password or if there is any escape character.

sample sqoop command that i am trying to execute is given below

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;database=SampleDB --username username --password samplepassword; --table sampleTable -m 1 --target-dir="/manish/"
```

Please note password is ending with **;**

I have to run this command in non-interactive way from python script. Any help in this regard  will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with writing a shell script if you need to use a semicolon ( ; ) in your parameter, you have to escape it in a shell using the backslash (forming  \; ). Your shell will automatically transform that to a single semicolon prior to passing the parameter to Sqoop. Similarly, you might need to enclose some of your parameters into single or double quotes on the command line to enter parameters with spaces; the shell will remove the enclosing quotes before passing the parameter to Sqoop.

More details are on: http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-517medusia/Apache-Sqoop-71.html

Comment: This doesn't work as it starts considering " as part of password and authentication fails.

Comment: " will not be considered as part of the password parameter.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the possible solution. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, for the time being somehow I managed to get rid of semicolon from the password by resetting the password. Though will try this later

Comment: sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;database=SampleDB" --username username --password samplepassword -e "SELECT column1 FROM table1 where column2 = 'manish'  AND $CONDITIONS" --target-dir="/location1/"  When i try executing this command it gives me error  Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'manish'.